# Warping without K / PPY, PPX, Focal - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been scanning OpenCV's library for weeks and haven't found any solution that covers my problem.. Which leads me to think that it just might be impossible.

If anyone has any input at all, I'd be forever grateful. It doesn't have to be a thorough answer, it could simply be a comment saying "it's not possible" - and I'd accept that :).

**Anyhow, on to the problem:**

I'm passing in a Quaternion from a device and calculating the Rodrigues angles successfully **<-- no problem with that.**

The problem is the PPY,PPX,Focal fields that really makes no absolute sense to me. It seems the only way to achieve accurate values for those fields, is if you calibrate the camera before.

But calibrating isn't even an option in my project.

**So my question is:**

Is there anything else I could use other than what I currently use that utilizes the rotation matrix without the need of PPY,PPX,Focal?

Simply put, is there any function I could use that just warps the images according to the rotation matrix?

**Further explanation:**

I currently use:

```
warper->warp(img, K, cameras[img_idx].R, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_REFLECT, imgWarped);
warper->warp(mask, K, cameras[img_idx].R, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, maskWarped);
```

But `K` utilizes `PPY,PPX,Focal` from `cameraParams`. If these fields are incorrect - it will relate to the result.

To my understanding, the only way to get accurate `PPY,PPX,Focal` fields is if you calibrate the camera. But calibrating the camera is impossible in my project.

So, is there a way to warp x amounts of images based on knowing their width/height & the rotation matrix?

**Picture of my problem:**

[image: problem]

Parameters behind problem:

```
cameras_global[imageCounter].ppx = 0.5 * image.size().width;
cameras_global[imageCounter].ppy = 0.5 * image.size().height;
cameras_global[imageCounter].focal = image.size().width * M_SQRT2;
```

Calculating Rodrigues:

```
double x = axisAngles[0];
double y = axisAngles[1];
double z = axisAngles[2];
double angle = axisAngles[3];

Mat input = (Mat_<float>(1,3) <<  x, y, z);

Mat cameraMatrix;
Rodrigues(input * angle, cameraMatrix);
input.release();
cameraMatrix.copyTo(cameras_global[imageCounter].R);
```

Axis Angles:

```
cv::Vec4f calculateAxisAnglesFromQuat(double qw, double qx, double qy, double qz){
    double angle = 2 * acos(qw);

    double x = qx / sqrt(1-qw*qw);
    double y = qy / sqrt(1-qw*qw);
    double z = qz / sqrt(1-qw*qw);

    return cv::Vec4f(x,y,z,angle);
}
```

Thanks for reading this lengthy explanation. I hope it makes sense! In case it doesn't, feel free to drop a comment and I'll try to re-write this until it does :)

Comment: Are you really sure there is no way you can calibrate the camera? _Why_ is calibration not even an option? Without a precise calibration, I think the best you can do is assume some _approximate_ values for the three parameters, but you'd have to live with the resulting error. Maybe, though, there is a way to calibrate/optimize the parameters on-the-fly from the images you have. Could you briefly outline what your images are showing?

Comment: I've updated my question with an image that portrays the outline of my problem. Basically, the rotation matrix is correct, however, the `ppy,ppx,focal` values are incorrect which leads to the problem. Calibration isn't an option because this code is supposed to stand behind a "stitcher" project. -- I don't think I can convince the users to pull out a checkerboard whenever they want to capture images. @mindriot

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time right now to research a proper answer, but at least I can say that _in principle_ it's possible. I'm not sure how much OpenCV offers you out-of-the-box though. But in [Bundle Adjustment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_adjustment) you can, in principle, optimize calibration parameters as well as camera poses. The [Panotools wiki](http://wiki.panotools.org/Lens_correction_model) could be a good starting point.

Comment: Of course.. I've tried matching features & doing bundle adjustment. It works beautifully! However, I'm trying to eliminate that process entirely by only relying on the device rotation. Here's a company that does what I'm looking to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2K-m3BRd3s

Answer (score 0):

ppx and ppy are half of image dimension, so it wont give any error. Focal length calculation introduces error. If you are completely relying on device rotation, you should use focal of device, not image.size().width * M_SQRT2

focal(in pixel) = image width(in pixel)*focal(in mm)/sensor width(mm)

But this might not yield perfect result always.Actually it depends on how accurate your device rotation information is.
Bundle adjustment (if enough distributed features are there), will give the best output. I would suggest using bundle adjustment. Also I dont think the app(youtube link you gave) is using device rotation only.

Comment: Focal of the device will never account to the focal needed. I.e. Focal of the device is only approx 35, but the only number that works is 6-700+.

Comment: which device are you using? You can calculate focal length in pixel by using sensor size(in mm) and resolution(in pixel) and focal length(in mm)

Comment: iPhone 5. Even by doing CAMERA_FOCAL_MM * 72.0 / 25.4, the number is still only ~99.0.

Comment: what is 72 and 25.4?

Comment: The openCV focal value seems to be calculated from CAMERA_FOCAL_MM which I presume is the camera focal length in millimeters, which then gets converted to inches (/ 25.4). But by no stretch of imagination, either the true focal length of ~4.5mm or the 35mm equivalent focal length of ~28mm adds up to ~700 which is the only value that truly works.

Comment: Nonetheless, I think I'm going about this so wrong. What do you propose?

Comment: I checked camera sensor width is 4.54mm and focal length is 4.12mm, Now imagine an image of 640*480 then focal in pixel = 640*4.12/4.54 = 580

Comment: Wow. For once, that actually makes sense :) Thank you so much! However, the images still seem to have the same error.. Maybe it's the way I'm calculating Rodrigues? I simply compose a (3,1) rotation matrix with the axis angles and multiply that rotation matrix by the angle.. I.e. (Rodrigues * angle), -- then pass it to Rodrigues(result,output);

Comment: Oh, and after all of that, I have to call `wave_correct_horizontal` in order for it to not result in memory failure.

Comment: I've updated my question with the exact code that I'm using to calculate Rodrigues angles.

Comment: If you have correct _axisAngles_ , then it should give correct result. From where are you getting _axisAngles_ data ?

Comment: I've updated my question once more :). I'm getting the Quaternion from [CMDeviceMotion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMAttitude/quaternion).

Comment: Another thing that doesn't make sense... Focal in pixels are is normally `([focal length in mm]*[resolution]/[sensor size in mm])`, so, shouldn't it be `(4.12*(width*height)/4.54)` ?